# Prevent memory leaks in Python; cyclic references

Tags: python, memory-leaks

Yesterday, I've struggled with memory leaks in some code.

So, code without excessive details:

```
from typing import List


class Something(object):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.something_new = None


class SomethingNew(object):

    def __init__(self, i: int = 0, something: Something = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.i = i
        self.something = something


def add_something(collection: List[Something], i: int):
    something = Something()
    something.something_new = SomethingNew(i, something)
    collection.append(something)


def check_memory(collection: List[Something]):
    # for e in collection:
    #     e.something_new.something = None
    collection.clear()


def main():
    collection = list()
    for i in range(1, 1024 * 128):
        add_something(collection, i)

    check_memory(collection)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

If we switch on manual cutting of references (uncomment commented lines). All'll work correct. The memory will release after exit from memory_check method. For example, we could check it with library: https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/.

Have anyone the best practices to prevent manual cutting of cyclic references? I'll be very appreciate for any advises. I believe that true "pythonic way" exists for solve that problem.